# measuring angle between a wall-plane and a floor-plane using android sensors

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, sensors

I want to use my phone's sensors to measure the angle between a ground-plane and a wall-plane.
So first, I'd put the phone straight up on the floor, push a button to calibrate (store the angle of the floor as reference orientation), then put the phone against the wall and see what the angle-difference is. (and display the result compared to the standard 90 degree difference)

What is the best way to measure this angle ?
I'm getting lost in the options with accelerometer sensor, gravity sensor, linear acceleration, getRotationMatrix etc..

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result. In essence, your question is "build this for me" right now without more details.

Comment: Sounds like the Gravity Sensor is what you want. Depending on the angle the "amount" of acceleration (gravity) will vary accordingly.

Comment: See also [*Sensors Overview*](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use accelerometer or linear acceleration x,y,z readings and calculate **any of the component angle with respect to gravity vector** in both positions.The difference will give you required angle